# get local path of an uploaded file in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to open an uploaded csv file in the clean function of a django form.

The code looks like this:

```
def clean(self):
        file_csv = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
        records = csv.reader(open('file_csv.name, 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

how do I get the local path of file_csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this work ? It's using basic python though...

```
import os
os.path.abspath(file_csv.name)
```